# Most efficient Django query to get the objects and their related

Tags: python, django

I have this model:

```
class Institution(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, db_index=True)
    aliases = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True)
```

I would like to make the most efficient query that return all `Institution` where `name` contains the search term AND their `aliases` `Institution`. I came with the solution below that work but I was wondering if there's a simpler/more efficient way to achieve this?

```
base_query = Institution.objects.filter(name__icontains='term')
pk_query = Q(pk__in=base_query)
aliases_query = Q(aliases__in=base_query)
final_query = Institution.objects.filter(pk_query|aliases_query).distinct()
```

Here is the SQL of this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `app_institution`.`id`, `app_institution`.`name`
FROM `app_institution` LEFT OUTER JOIN `app_institution_aliases`
ON (`app_institution`.`id` = `app_institution_aliases`.`from_institution_id`)
WHERE (`app_institution`.`id`
IN (SELECT U0.`id` FROM `app_institution` U0 WHERE U0.`name` LIKE %term% )
OR `app_institution_aliases`.`to_institution_id`
IN (SELECT U0.`id` FROM `app_institution` U0 WHERE U0.`name` LIKE %term% ))
ORDER BY `app_institution`.`name` ASC LIMIT 21
```

### UPDATE

By looking at the 2 first answers I got, I think I should specify more clearly what I want as results.

I want the UNION of

- the results of the `base_query` (`Institution` where `name` contains the search term)

WITH

- `aliases` of each of the `Institution` return by the `base_query` (theses `aliases`' `name` don't need to contains the search term).

Done in an inefficient (but easily understandable) way will be like that:

```
base_query = Institution.objects.filter(name__icontains='term')
results= set(base_query)
for institution in base_query:
    results.update(institution.aliases.all())
```

### 2nd UPDATE

Thinking about S.Lott answer, I finally figure out a way to do it with two queries that I join together after.

```
base_query = Institution.objects.filter(name__icontains='term')
results= set(base_query)
aliases_query = Institution.objects.filter(aliases__in=base_query)
results.update(aliases_query)
```

I did some small benchmarks and this solution take around half time of the one with the one big query.

But something that I forgot to take into account is the impact on the ordering...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Union queries -- like this -- are difficult.

It's important to review the use cases to be sure you **really** need to conflate two separate collections (by name and by alias) like this.  Sometimes the web page can be presented with two collections, removing the need for a union.

Using `Q` objects to build "or" conditions is one way to create a union.

Assembling a separate collection from the two queries is another solution.

```
name_query = Institution.objects.filter(name__icontains='term')
aliases_query = Institution.objects.filter(aliases__name__icontains='term')
final_query = list(name_query) + list(aliases_query)
```

The only way to know which is better is to benchmark the alternatives.  The "complexity" of the SQL query text doesn't really mean much, because there are so many optimization steps inside an RDBMS.

Comment: Unfortunately I **really** have this need. It's for an autocomplete field, so I need to show search term results and their aliases. And see my UPDATE. Thanks.

Comment: "Unfortunately I really have this need."?  What?  There are two solutions in this answer.  What does your comment mean?

Comment: It means that firstly, as you said, I reviewed the use case and unfortunately, I really have this need. Then, secondly, I looked at the other part of your answer where you expose 2 approaches, `Q` to build "or" and assembling 2 queries. The `Q` approach is the one I'm using now. So I evaluated the other one, and I didn't find a way to do it with only two queries. The only way I found is the one in my UPDATE and it will add one query for each result of the first query. Probably not really efficient in most cases.

Comment: "Probably not really efficient in most cases"?  Did you measure?  You can't assume; you must measure.

Comment: I was pretty sure you will say that!  You're right that to be sure, I need to benchmark it. But something that I know without benchmarking is that with this solution, there will be a lot of SQL queries when the user will type a few characters and the number of SQL queries will declined as the user will add more characters. Look at my second update. Thanks. Now I need to think about the order I want before going any further.

Answer (score 0):

this:

```
Institution.objects.filter(name__icontains='term', aliases__name__icontains='terms')
```

Comment: @Etienne If you want to have some order you must use some order_by() in your queryset and dont forget to replace the set() by a list() and use extends() instead of update()